# Cannot set 24 h format on UIDatePicker in iOS14

Tags: swift, uikit, uidatepicker, time-format

I can't set `UIDatePicker` to be in 24 hours format, when the style is set to `.compact`.

I **can** set the format to 24 hours when the Date Picker's style is set to `.wheels` or `.inline`.

As seen in the code below, I set the locale on my Date Formatter to "en_GB" to get 24h format. The simulator is set to United States as region when reproducing this.

If I don't set the locale, then the `.compact` style also presents the AM/PM selectors, which is not present when using the code below.

This is my code, the `UIDatePicker` is added as the only item in the Storyboard:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // setting this should give 24 hr format also in United States region, but it doesn't 
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB") 
    
        datePicker.locale = dateFormatter.locale
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.compact
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here, or can't it be done for the `.compact` style?

Comment: Try changing to 24h format in your device's settings

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked. However, it is unfortunately not a solution if you have users all over the world and you want to enforce 24h format in the app. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I submitted an answer for this question. Please mark it as accepted if it helps you

Answer (score 4):

There is no way that you can change the format of your `UIDatePicker` in your app.
The format of the Date Picker is the same format that the user selected in the Settings app. Simply go to `Settings -> General -> Date and Time` to change the format on your device.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented with this in iOS 14 Simulator. It appears the ordering of assigning properties matters.

This works:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB") as Locale // 24 hour time
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
```

This does **not** work:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB") as Locale // 24 hour time
```

Placing the Locale setting last appears to not work and exposes a bug in UIKit where the am/pm setting is not exposed, leading to only hours 01-12 setting possible.

Comment: I see something somewhat similar. When I set the "minute interval" to e.g. "5", then the bug would appear (only 1-12 available instead of 0-23)